# Javascript - Make switch: default restart prompt

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, default

I am trying to ask the user a simple question:

```js
// Write your code below!
var food = prompt("Do you like waffles?");

switch (food) {
    case "yes":
    case "Yes":
        alert("Good!");
        break;
    case "no":
    case "No":
        alert("But why!");
        break;
    default:
        var food = prompt("That's not an answer, Do you like waffles?");
        break;
}
```

The default works but only once. I want to re-prompt the user if he/she enters an answer that is not yes or no infinitely. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function askForFood( questionArgument ){
  var food = prompt( questionArgument );
  switch (food.toLowerCase()) { // be DRY! Use lowercase!
    case "yes":                 // And lowercase it is!
      alert("Good!");
      break;
    case "no":
      alert("But why!");
      break;
    default:
      askForFood("That's not an answer, Do you like waffles?"); // to hell with it
      break;
  }
}

askForFood("Do you like waffles?"); // First time ask nicely
```

Why the above works?
Cause the use of a `function` that's able to do repeat the work more times.
Simply pass your `"Question"` as an argument to the function.
`case default:` with that same function call, but usign a different question this time.

P.S: thanks to the use of `toLowerCase()` the user can also write "yeS" and your program will play ball with friends without caring much...

---

If it's not for school, you could also play with your code and do it (I like it!) like this:

```js
var questionary = {
  "yes" : "Good!",
  "no"  : "But why!",
};

function askForFood( question ){
  var answer = prompt( question ).toLowerCase();
  if(answer in questionary) alert( questionary[answer] ); // Self explanatory
  else askForFood( "That's not an answer" ); // ♫ do it again!
}
askForFood("Do you like waffles?");
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm, nicely commented too.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to re-evaluate the second prompt as it doesnt actually go anywhere. You would need to separate it as such:

```
function askMe() {
   var food = prompt("Do you like waffles?");
   switch (food) {
    case "yes":
    case "Yes":
        alert("Good!");
        break;
    case "no":
    case "No":
        alert("But why!");
        break;
    default:
        askMe();

        break;
  }
}

askMe();
```

Comment: The code works fine. Should be upvoted not downvoted.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen You have to actually run it.. As in call the function `askMe()`

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have received a working answer, but this is the perfect application for a while loop, and I see you havn't learned how to use them. Look how much shorter it is!

```
var food = "Do you like waffles?";
while ((food = window.prompt(food, "yes")) != "yes" && food != "no") {
    food = "That\'s not an answer, do you like waffles?";
}
window.alert("You said " + food + ".");
```

So here's how this works.

After the word while, there is a long line of code surrounded by brackets. It's a condition. The condition says "if the answer provided isn't yes, and it isn't no" . As long as the condition remains true, the while loop will repeat itself.

First, I set the variable food to the message I want to use. Then, in the condition of the while loop, I created a prompt:

```
food = window.prompt(food, "yes")
```

You'll notice that I am reusing my old food variable here. I didn't want to create a new one, so I reused my old one. You'll notice that I set the message in the prompt to be the previous value of the food variable. Also notice that for the sake of user friendliness, I made the default message "yes" .

If the value of the prompt doesn't equal yes or no, it sets the value of the food variable to our second message. Then, it does the condition of the while loop over again, and again, and again, until we get a yes or no answer.

Finally, when the user answers yes or no, the condition of the while loop is no longer true, so it skips past the while loop to tell the user their answer.

It's good to experiment around with different ways to do things, to see if you can shorten your code and improve performance! Just be sure you have made it clear what to answer, because otherwise the user will be stuck with an infinitely repeating prompt and won't know what to do, and pressing Cancel won't help because it isn't a yes or no answer.

You could even improve this code further by checking if the user pressed Cancel, and then stop the while loop as well.

```
var food = "Do you like waffles?";
while ((food = window.prompt(food, "yes")) && food != "yes" && food != "no") {
    food = "That\'s not an answer, do you like waffles?";
}
if (!food) {
    window.alert("Aw, you cancelled out!");
} else {
    window.alert("You said " + food + ".");
}
```

Here, I changed the condition in the while loop. We first check if the food variable can even be set to the prompt! If it can't, it's because the user must've pressed Cancel. Later, we also check if the food variable is set, because we don't want to tell the user what they said, if they pressed Cancel and didn't say anything.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have any mechanism in there to perform a loop.  Try surrounding it with a `while` loop.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do that since I am new to javascript. Can you walk me through how?